# How to ignore all related data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

User.php

```
 public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class)->withTimestamps();
}

public function hasRole($role)
{
    if($this->roles()->where('name',$role)->first())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
public function teams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class)->withTimeStamps();
    }
```

Team.php

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withTimeStamps();
    }
```

Role.php

```
 public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Now i want to get all users that are not engaged with any teams and whose role is member

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this helper:

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence

```
$users = User::doesntHave('teams')->get();
```

-- EDIT

```
$users = User::doesntHave('teams')->whereHas('roles', function($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'member');
})->get();
```

Comment: can you help me little more

Comment: @TanvirAhmed is it related to the same question?

Comment: actually i want all the users whose role is member and not engaged with teams, and i forgot to add this

Comment: @TanvirAhmed I don't know your role type, nor how you have it connected to the user, but take a look at the edit, it should give you an idea. You can chain any query that you want.